DataTrigger not working when created Dynamically
After solving my last issue: ExpandoObject Datagrid rendering issue
now i have an issue with my DataTrigger that i created dynamically. It seems to be fine according to the code but it doesn't work. The DataTrigger verify if the value of column "Spec_X" or "Spec_Y" is True or False. If True, the Foreground of the TextBlock will be "FireBrick".
Here's my code:
Binding Binding_X = new Binding();
Binding_X.Path = new PropertyPath("X" + int.Parse(Test_Num["Test_Num"].ToString()));

Binding Binding_Y = new Binding();
Binding_Y.Path = new PropertyPath("Y" + int.Parse(Test_Num["Test_Num"].ToString()));

DataGridTextColumn Column_X = new DataGridTextColumn
    {
       Header = "X",
       Binding = Binding_X,
       Width = 50,
       SortMemberPath = "X" + int.Parse(Test_Num["Test_Num"].ToString())
    };

Style columnStyle_X = new Style(typeof(TextBlock));
DataTrigger Trigger_X = new DataTrigger();
Trigger_X.Binding = new Binding("Spec_X" + int.Parse(Test_Num["Test_Num"].ToString()));
Trigger_X.Value = True;
Trigger_X.Setters.Add(
    new Setter(
    TextBlock.ForegroundProperty,
    new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Firebrick)));
columnStyle_X.Triggers.Add(Trigger_X);
Column_X.ElementStyle = columnStyle_X;

DataGridTextColumn Column_Y = new DataGridTextColumn
    {
       Header = "Y",
       Binding = Binding_Y,
       Width = 50,
       SortMemberPath = "Y" + int.Parse(Test_Num["Test_Num"].ToString())
    };

Style columnStyle_Y = new Style(typeof(TextBlock));
DataTrigger Trigger_Y = new DataTrigger();
Trigger_Y.Binding = new Binding("Spec_Y" + int.Parse(Test_Num["Test_Num"].ToString()));
Trigger_Y.Value = True;
Trigger_Y.Setters.Add(
    new Setter(
    TextBlock.ForegroundProperty,
    new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Firebrick)));
columnStyle_Y.Triggers.Add(Trigger_Y);
Column_Y.ElementStyle = columnStyle_Y;

I filled my DataTable and Bind the defaultview to the DataGrid.
foreach (DataRow dt in main.Table_performance_AVG.Rows)
{
   DataRow row = List_Table_Performance_Data[i].NewRow();

   row["Recipe"] = list_recipe.Any() == false ? dt["Recipe_Name"].ToString() : "";
   row["Date"] = ((DateTime)dt["Date"]).ToString("M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss").ToString();
   row["X" + dt["Test_Num"].ToString()] = dt[i + count].ToString() == "-99999" ? null : (double?)dt[i + count];
   row["Y" + dt["Test_Num"].ToString()] = dt[i + 1 + count].ToString() == "-99999" ? null : (double?)dt[i + 1 + count];
   row["Spec_X" + dt["Test_Num"].ToString()] = True;
   row["Spec_Y" + dt["Test_Num"].ToString()] = True;

   Table_Performance_Data.Rows.Add(row);
}

DataGrid.ItemsSource = Table_Performance_Data.DefaultView;


Since you didn't provide a completed sample, I can't test for sure. But if you DataGrid can display values of "Spec_X" and "Spec_Y" correctly, just changing Trigger_X.Binding and Trigger_Y.Binding's value from your original to new Binding() should work.
